# subject verb agreement question - was or were?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

The other THING that made that night special for me WAS/WERE the GUESTS.

Do we bring "was" because of "thing" or "were" because of "guests"?

Comment: I wouldn't get too worked up about this one. Googgle Books claims 49 written instances of [*(the) **thing** that bothered him **were** (some plural noun)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22THING+that+bothered+him+were%22). Most native speakers probably wouldn't even notice the subject/verb form "plurality" clash in such contexts, particularly given that the common alternative ***what** bothered him...* can validly be followed by either a singular ***or*** plural verb form. This is more a matter of pedantry than what usages ordinary native speakers actually produce and accept.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "was" instead of "were." After all, it's "subject-verb agreement" because the verb must agree with the subject, not the object. To better remember this, you can try replacing the entire subject with "it" if it's singular.

Comment: +1 a couple of notes. *the guests* is a Complement of the verb, but it's not the object (the verb *BE* cannot take an Object). 2) it might be good to clearly explain what the Subject is here.